# how should I change the sequence of a list

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

this is my code the creates a list of year + month

```
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            var list = new List<ArchiveViewModel>();
            for (var startDate = currentDate; startDate >= new DateTime(2012, 8, 1); startDate = startDate.AddMonths(-1))
            {
                list.Add(new ArchiveViewModel
                {
                    Month = startDate.Month,
                    Year = startDate.Year,
                    FormattedDate = startDate.ToString("MMMM, yyyy")
                });
            }
            return PartialView("_ArchiveSidebar", list);
```

and this is my code in razor

```
@foreach (var archive in Model)
    {
        <ul>
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink(archive.FormattedDate, "Post", "Archive", new { year = archive.Year, month = archive.Month }, null)
            </li>
        </ul>   
}
```

in this case result is like this

```
    August, 2013
    July, 2013
    June, 2013
    May, 2013
    April, 2013
    March, 2013
    February, 2013
    January, 2013
    December, 2012
    November, 2012
    October, 2012
    September, 2012
    August, 2012
```

but I want something like this

```
August, 2013    July, 2013
June, 2013      May, 2013
April, 2013     March, 2013
February, 2013  January, 2013
December, 2012  November, 2012
October, 2012   September, 2012
August, 2012
```

obviously data is static, how should do that??

Comment: This is not CSS job, but JavaScript's job.

Comment: There is a ton of info missing, to be able to only remotely answering your question.

Comment: Tables? What about no.

Comment: @Terry I was asking Eric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not provided enough information on if the data is static or dynamic, what kind of element is it wrapped inside.

I will answer you based on my understanding of your question.

You can use List to format the data in a way you want. Put all the items in an unordered list (i.e. `UL`) like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="somelist">
<ul>
<li>August, 2013</li>
<li>July, 2013</li>
<li>June, 2013</li>
<li>May, 2013</li>
<li>April, 2013</li>
<li>March, 2013</li>
<li>February, 2013</li>
<li>January, 2013</li>
<li>December, 2012</li>
<li>November, 2012</li>
<li>October, 2012</li>
<li>September, 2012</li>
<li>August, 2012</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And, then set the width of the wrapper div and use display-block on each list item with fixed width so that it makes a pair of two in a row. Like this:

**CSS**

```
#somelist
{
    width:500px;
    padding:10px;
}
#somelist > ul
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

#somelist > ul > li
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    padding:2px;    
}
```

**Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/3bwyj/1/**

### Update

Replace your code with the following and use the CSS that I have provided:

```
<div id="somelist">
  <ul>
    @foreach (var archive in Model)
        {
          <li>
              @Html.ActionLink(archive.FormattedDate, "Post", "Archive", new { year = archive.Year, month = archive.Month }, null)
          </li>
        }
  </ul>   
</div>
```

Note that I have added a DIV wrapper for the UL and don't forget to change the ID of the div from somelist to something else.

Comment: Please see updated code. your wrapper DIV and UL must be outside the foreach loop otherwise both will be generated multiple times along with the LI.

Comment: thanks, could you please tell me how can I reduce the space between two generated column?

Comment: to reduce space just set `#somelist{width:280px;}` and `#somelist > ul > li {width:120px;}`

Comment: Exactly as Vector said.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's a `php` foreach loop.

PHPFiddle http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3y5-ymg

html/php

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php
    foreach ($Result as $Row)
    {
        ?>
        <div class="col">
            <?php echo $Row ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }?>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width: 600px; // you can set this to what you want
}
.col {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
}
```

You could do the same with a list, the logic is the same.

Comment: Why do you presume that he's using PHP?

Comment: Because the data looks database driven

Comment: Even if it was DB driven why PHP and not ASP.NET or Ruby or something else?

Comment: the logic is the same

Comment: Yes, but some people don't understand PHP at all and might get confused.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using [**nth-child**](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) pseudo class.

**HTML:**

```
<li>August, 2013</li>
<li>July, 2013</li>
<li>June, 2013</li>
<li>May, 2013</li>
<li>April, 2013</li>
<li>March, 2013</li>
<li>February, 2013</li>
<li>January, 2013</li>
<li>December, 2012</li>
<li>November, 2012</li>
<li>October, 2012</li>
<li>September, 2012</li>
<li>August, 2012</li>
```

**CSS:**

```
li:nth-child(odd) {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fZ9db/)

[**Update Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fZ9db/1/), removing bullets.

Comment: What about IE older versions?

Comment: @Learner Latest version of IE 9 and 10 supports CSS3 right.  OP haven't mentioned.  But there may be some work around.  Also OP haven't mentioned in his question.

Comment: Yes, but a lot of people are still using IE8 or lower versions. As a best practice we should provide him a generic solution.

Comment: @Learner Yup I accept. By Microsoft really wants to move to latest.  The count down already started [IE7 < 1% worldwide](http://theie7countdown.com/) and [IE8 10% worldwide](http://theie8countdown.com/).  IE6 RIP.

Comment: Agree, but 10% is still a lot of people worldwide. I think we should build cross browser solution until IE gets the status of RIP officially.